# Using RestTemplate in Spring. Exception- Not enough variables available to expand

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am trying to access the contents of an API and I need to send a URL using RestTemplate.

```
String url1 = "http://api.example.com/Search?key=52ddafbe3ee659bad97fcce7c53592916a6bfd73&term=&limit=100&sort={\"price\":\"desc\"}";

OutputPage page = restTemplate.getForObject(url1, OutputPage .class);
```

But, I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"price"'
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:220)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:317)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:46)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.expand(UriTemplate.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:501)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:239)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:26)
```

If I remove the sort criteria, it is working  properly.
I need to parse the JSON using sort criteria.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I got this error from application.properties file. I found that I had missed $ before {...}. Fixed it and it worked.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The root cause is that `RestTemplate` considers curly braces `{...}` in the given URL as a placeholder for URI variables and tries to replace them based on their name. For example

```
{pageSize}
```

would try to get a URI variable called `pageSize`. These URI variables are specified with some of the other overloaded [`getForObject`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) methods. You haven't provided any, but your URL expects one, so the method throws an exception.

One solution is to make a `String` object containing the value

```
String sort = "{\"price\":\"desc\"}";
```

and provide a real URI variable in your URL

```
String url1 = "http://api.example.com/Search?key=52ddafbe3ee659bad97fcce7c53592916a6bfd73&term=&limit=100&sort={sort}";
```

You would call your `getForObject()` like so

```
OutputPage page = restTemplate.getForObject(url1, OutputPage.class, sort);
```

I strongly suggest you do not send any JSON in a request parameter of a GET request  but rather send it in the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 13):

If the solution suggested by [sotirios-delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) is a little difficult to implement in a scenario, and if the URI string containing curly braces and other characters is guaranteed to be correct, it might be simpler to pass the encoded URI string to a method of `RestTemplate` that hits the `ReST` server.

The URI string can be built using [UriComponentsBuilder.build()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#build--), encoded using [UriComponents.encode()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html#encode--), and sent using [RestTemplate.exchange()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-) like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> requestRestServer()
{
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(rawValidUrl)
            .queryParams(
                    (LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>) allRequestParams);
    UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode();
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriComponents.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,
            entity, String.class);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Building, encoding, and extracting URI have been seperated out for clarity in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 9):

You can URL encode the parameter values:

```
String url1 = "http://api.example.com/Search?key=52ddafbe3ee659bad97fcce7c53592916a6bfd73&term=&limit=100&sort=";

org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec codec = new org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec();
url1 = url1 + codec.encode("{\"price\":\"desc\"}");
OutputPage page = restTemplate.getForObject(url1, OutputPage.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a specific UriTemplateHandler in your restTemplate. This handler would just ignore uriVariables :

```
UriTemplateHandler skipVariablePlaceHolderUriTemplateHandler = new UriTemplateHandler() {
    @Override
    public URI expand(String uriTemplate, Object... uriVariables) {
        return retrieveURI(uriTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    public URI expand(String uriTemplate, Map<String, ?> uriVariables) {
        return retrieveURI(uriTemplate);
    }

    private URI retrieveURI(String uriTemplate) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uriTemplate).build().toUri();
    }
};

restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(skipVariablePlaceHolderUriTemplateHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append a variable key to the URL and give the value using the **`restTemplate.getForObject()`** method.

Example:

```
String url = "http://example.com/api?key=12345&sort={data}";
String data="{\"price\":\"desc\"}";

OutputPage page = restTemplate.getForObject(url, OutputPage.class, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode url before using RestTemplate

```
URLEncoder.encode(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```