# How to encode url string with object in request parameters spring

Tags: java, encoding, uri, resttemplate

I.m trying to do request with the object as a request parameter in my Spring application.

```
new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://127.0.0.1:8080/items?filter={\"level\":\"BIG\"}", Item.class);
```

But get error:

[image]

As I discovered, the problem occurs when UriBuilder parses the string with url. I.e. new URI(...) gives the error. When I do the same request with Postman I get a desirable response. How I can properly encode url? I`m tried to use java.net.URLEncoder but this gives "IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute" error.

UPDATE:

Filter class in the request is used to do parameterized query ( Query() ) in mongodb in the remote server. Filter class:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Filter {

private Map<String, String> criteria;

@JsonAnySetter
public void add(String key, String value) {
    if (criteria == null) {
        criteria = new HashMap<>();
    }

    criteria.put(key, value);
}
}
```

Item object class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Item {
private String id;
private String name;
private Instant timestamp;
}
```

Comment: can you add the Item object please

Comment: Item is a simple data class. Filter class in the request is used to do parameterized query ( Query() )  in mongodb in the remote server. But I even can't do request with Filter object.

Comment: is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819210/using-resttemplate-in-spring-exception-not-enough-variables-available-to-expan

Answer (score 0):

i have problem like yours and i solve it using following snippet code

```
UriComponentsBuilder renewURIBuilder= UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080").path("/items").queryParam("filter", "{'level':BIG}");
UriComponents uriComponent=renewURIBuilder.build(true);
URI uri=uriComponent.toUri();
```

then call your resttemplate like the following

```
new RestTemplate().getForObject(uri, Item.class);
```

hope it help you

Comment: i tried it and working fine guys