# Trying to make a request with or without parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I´m trying to make a request with or without parameters, according the code below:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/threshold/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Threshold> listThreshold(@RequestParam(required = false) String categoria, @RequestParam(required = false) String kpi, @RequestParam(required = false) String data, @RequestParam(required = false) String hora) {
    
    return thresholdQuery.listThreshold(categoria, kpi, data, hora);
}
```

But when I call the endpoint this way:

```
http://localhost:8081/threshold/list?categoria=casa
```

I got the error below:

```
Not enough variable values available to expand 'categoria=casa'
```

Comment: Does changing `@RequestParam(required = false)` to `@RequestParam(value="categoria",required = false)` work (same thing with `kpi`,`data` and `hora`)?

Comment: How do you call the endpoint?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/threshold/list?categoria=casa

Comment: Are you directly calling it from browser.. Or you're using RestTemplate? If you're using RestTemplate share the code for calling this api

Comment: dan1st I made your changes, but it still with the same error.

Comment: I´m calling from postman

Comment: from browser gives the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using RestTemplate in Spring. Exception- Not enough variables available to expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819210/using-resttemplate-in-spring-exception-not-enough-variables-available-to-expan)

Comment: this didn´t help me, because I don´t using restTemplate. I just want to call the endpoint above with or without a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be 'name' instead of 'value'

```
@RequestParam(name="categoria",required = false)
```