# How to pass %22 as filter in restTemplate in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url, resttemplate, victoriametrics

1.requestURL = [https://test.env123.com:8081/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=test.link.packets{billid=%22P1yhABCnWJ7WhI%22}&start=2023-08-10T01:02:03Z&end=2023-08-26T01:02:03Z](https://test.env123.com:8081/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=test.link.packets%7Bbillid=%22P1yhABCnWJ7WhI%22%7D&start=2023-08-10T01:02:03Z&end=2023-08-26T01:02:03Z)

ResponseEntity result  = restTemplate.getForEntity(requestURL, String.class);

2. String filter = "";
   requestURL = [https://test.env123.com:8081/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=test.link.packets{filter}&start=2023-08-10T01:02:03Z&end=2023-08-26T01:02:03Z](https://test.env123.com:8081/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=test.link.packets%7Bfilter%7D&start=2023-08-10T01:02:03Z&end=2023-08-26T01:02:03Z)

filter = "{billid=%22P1yhABCnWJ7WhI%22}";

ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange(requestURL, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class, filter);

I tried both the ways, none of them worked.

throws this exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'billid=%22P1yhABCnWJ7WhI%22'

How do I resolve such cases specially when URL has double quotes " and curly braces { } ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using RestTemplate in Spring. Exception- Not enough variables available to expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819210/using-resttemplate-in-spring-exception-not-enough-variables-available-to-expan)

Comment: No, the requestURL in mycase has %22 in {} whereas in the link provided is different. also filter is in mid of URL, whereas in the link provided was at the end of the URL"{sort}"

Comment: I don't have a way to test it right now, but would this work? 

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
String baseUrl = "https://test.env123.com:8081/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range";
String query = "test.link.packets{billid=\"P1yhABCnWJ7WhI\"}";
String start = "2023-08-10T01:02:03Z";
String end = "2023-08-26T01:02:03Z";
        

        
String requestURL = baseUrl + "?query=" + query + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end;
        
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(requestURL, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class);

Comment: I tried this but still getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when You are trying to send get requests with get parameters which contain some of the special symbols like *&, {, }, ?* and others you have to UrlEncode them, becaus when server sees & as eaxmple, he recognises it as and of previous parameter and waits for another parameter. Try pls to UrlEncode these params.

**Here is an example, You can use UriComponentsBuilder**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String baseUrl = "YOUR_API_URL";
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)
            .queryParam("query","test.link.packets{filter}")
            .queryParam("start","2023-08-10T01:02:03Z")
            .queryParam("end","2023-08-26T01:02:03Z");

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.toUriString(), String.class);
```

**UPDATED**

Here is another approach which will also work great. But note, if you are passing paramters into the url in this way, order matters, rest template will pass these params to the url, in order how they are passed in getForEntity function

```
// Create a RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String start = "2023-08-10T01:02:03Z";
String end = "2023-08-26T01:02:03Z";
String filter = "{billid=\"P1yhABCnWJ7WhI\"}";
// Define the URL with parameters or build it
String baseUrl = "https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/query_range?query=test.link.packets{filter}&start={start}&end={end}";
// Make the GET request and receive the response as ResponseEntity
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, String.class, filter, start, end);
```

Comment: Thank u so much !! 2nd approach worked fine.